# What does "anyone is ever" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Only in words is anyone ever omniscient.

which one is the correct understanding:

1. Only in words anyone could be omniscient
2. Only in words anyone was at least one time omniscient

Answer (score 4):

Your two paraphrases are not grammatical, because an initial *only* phrase at the start of a sentence triggers inversion.

The meaning is identical to *Nobody is ever omniscient except in words.*